# OpenSSL Error Starting Delphi-XE Datasnap Server on Linux64 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-18.04, delphi-xe, datasnap

Starting a DataSnap Server on Ubuntu 18.04 is causing some EThreadNameException followed by some EIdOSSL.CouldNotLoadSSLLibrary inside unit IdSSLOpenSSL at line 2319 (IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.Load  - Create Methode of TDataModule).(Delphi Version 10.3.2)

It is the source produced by the RAD Studio DataSnap Wizard. On Windows all is running without problems.

On Ubuntu openssl version is OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018.

I have also tried to deploy libcrypto.a and libssl.a directly to Scratch Dir but without influence.

Any Ideas.....How to additional configure OpenSSL?? I have recompiled OpenSSL to /opt/openssl following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126893/how-to-install-openssl-1-1-1-and-libssl-package

Comment: `EThreadNameException` is raised by `TThread.NameThreadForDebugging()`. The exception is supposed to be handled silently by the IDE debugger, and swallowed by the RTL. If you are seeing the exception at all then that functionality is not working properly on Embarcadero's end. [File a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: As for `EIdOSSL.CouldNotLoadSSLLibrary`, that is an Indy exception, and DataSnap uses Indy internally. Indy does not currently support OpenSSL 1.1.x at all ([work in progress](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183)). You need to use OpenSSL 1.0.2 instead (and yes, we are aware of the upcoming End-of-Life deadline for 1.0.2)

Comment: I will check out 1.0.2 and will give feedback at this channel

Comment: I have installed and checked openssl version 1.0.2t, but everything is the same

Comment: you can use Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to find out why Indy could not load OpenSSL (missing libs, or missing required exports), and use the `OpenSSLVersion()` function in the ` IdSSLOpenSSL` unit to get the version of OpenSSL that was loaded into memory (even if required exports are missing)

Comment: SSL_load_error_strings,
SSL_library_init,
SSLeay_version,
SSLeay,
CRYPTO_lock,
CRYPTO_num_locks,
CRYPTO_set_locking_callback,
CRYPTO_set_id_callback,
ERR_free_strings,
EVP_MD_CTX_init,
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_flags,
HMAC_CTX_init,
HMAC_CTX_cleanup,
CRYPTO_mem_leaks,
CRYPTO_set_mem_debug_functions,
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms,
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers,
OpenSSL_add_all_digests,
EVP_cleanup,
sk_num,
sk_new,
sk_new_null,
sk_free,
sk_push,
sk_dup,
sk_find,
sk_value is the result of WhichfailedToLoad OpenSSLVersion is empty

Comment: all of those functions mentioned were removed in OpenSSL 1.1. Which means your app is not loading 1.0.2.

Comment: is there any other option to set as LD_LIBRARY_PATH and Path echo $Path is given /opt/openssl/bin which openssl /opt/openssl/bin/openssl ; openssl version 1.0.2t; I have removed complete folder /opt/openssl/ with 1.1.1 and did some new install with 1.0.2t after this, cannot see any reason, why still 1.1.1 should be linked

Comment: Indy loads OpenSSL dynamically only when it is actually needed. At program startup, you can call Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function in the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to tell Indy which specific folder to load the OpenSSL lib files from, before doing anything else that needs OpenSSL to be loaded.

Comment: I have set the path with IdOpenSSLSetLibPath() and copied libcrypto.a and libssl.a into; now WhichFailedToLoad() is missing libcypto.so, but there is no libcrypto.so or .so1.0.2 or anything else only some libcrypto.pc, that is indeed cryptic

Comment: `.pc` files are not compiled library files, you need the `.so`/`.a` files

Comment: found relevant so files by locate libcrypto.so.1.0.2 ; got it running with IdopenSSLsetlibPath()